# How to create a custom tab icon in a Salesforce Managed Package

Tags: salesforce

Does anyone know how to create a custom icon for a managed package in Salesforce.  I see how to create a custom icon for a custom object tab that is stored in "My Personal Documents" but it will not allow this image to be part of the managed package.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is doable. Create a new folder and put the icon in the custom folder.
Now you can add it to the package (actually it will add the folder automatically if you add the tab).

Comment: Thanks Moti!!  I tried what you suggested, but after i built the managed package and installed it, the custom icon did not show.  I created a new folder in Documents, uploaded my image there.  Then i used that image on my custom tab.  Looked fine in my dev org.  I assumed it added it automatically as you suggested, but seems not to have.  Any other suggestions?